# Why new version of Node and React get me a blank page for a route?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm still new to Node and React. Thus, I will try my best to describe the problem. I was able to see some route with GET method in old version of React with create-react-app. But I updated React yesterday, now I can't see it anymore. I'm not sure if it's because of webpack(I googled it, but still don't understand what it is).

My React port is 3000, and Node listen to the port 5005, and I used to put proxy object in the package.json in client folder, now new version of React doesn't accept proxy as object anymore so I use a library like the following code under /src in order to make full stack project

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.use(proxy('/api/*', { target: 'http://localhost:5005' }));
};
```

I have a route in Node like this:

```
module.exports = (app) => {
app.get('/api/signup/thanks_confirmation', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
        <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 50px;">
            Thank you!!!! We will get back to you ASAP!!
        </div>
    `);
});
}
```

In the old version of React, when I open the new broswer and typed

```
localhost:3000/api/signup/thanks_confirmation
```

It will show the content like the route, but now I only got a blank page. However, if I have

```
localhost:5005/api/signup/thanks_confirmation
```

it will work. Does Facebook update the webpack or something? I'm really confused.

Comment: What does the network tab in dev tools show when you issue your request?

Comment: share the dose, the usage of proxy is inclear

Comment: @AlexMcMillan When I do http://localhost:3000/api/signup/thanks_confirmation, the network tab doesn't hit anything

Comment: @TalAvissar I think it's not proxy problem because I thought proxy is only for front-end issues http requests? And the code I have work before in old version